# Finding a linear path in a traversable structure

Tags: haskell, tree, traversal

Given a list of steps:

```
>>> let path = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
```

And a labeled `Tree`:

```
>>> import Data.Tree
>>> let tree = Node "item1" [Node "itemA" [], Node "item2" [Node "item3" []]]
```

I'd like a function that goes through the steps in `path` matching the labels in `tree` until it can't go any further because there are no more labels matching the steps. Concretely, here it falls when stepping into "item4" (for my use case I still need to specify the last matched step):

```
>>> trav path tree
["item3", "item4", "item5"]
```

If I allow `[String] -> Tree String -> [String]` as the type of `trav` I could write a recursive function that steps in both structures at the same time until there are no labels to match the step. But I was wondering if a more general type could be used, specifically for `Tree`. For example: `Foldable t => [String] -> t String -> [String]`. If this is possible, how `trav` could be implemented?

I suspect there could be a way to do it using `lens`.

Comment: It's a little unclear how this path should be used. One method is the tree Zipper. Also compare just using Foldable.toList. Vanilla traversals have a fixed order, so they won't allow you to index by a path themselves.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson, I edited it to make it more clear. I hope it can be understood.

Comment: This reminds me of an xml xpath query....  You might want to look at how xml-conduit does something similar.  Note that xpath allows multiple matches at a given level, and uses the list monad to concatinate results.

Comment: @jamshidh, in my concrete case I can assume that there won't be repeated labels at the same level. That's also a reason why I want more general trees, for example, to use `Set`s instead of lists for branches to enforce label uniqueness at each level.

Comment: Data.Tree uses Haskell lists to hold the items (with potential repeats), perhaps you meant to define a different type of tree, perhaps using Data.Map?  At any rate, I still think monads are the way to go, because each lookup could fail (ie- an item might not exist in the map at that level), and you need to chain these together.

Comment: Prisms could capture whether or not the next step is possible. You'd want some kind of reader monad structure to capture the current path. I'll noodle on it now that I better understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please let's use `type Label = String`. String is not exactly descriptive and might not be ideal in the end...

Now. To use `Traversable`, you need to pick a suitable `Applicative` that can contain the information you need for deciding what to do in its "structure". You only need to pass back information after a match has *failed*. That sounds like some `Either`!

A guess would thus be `Either [Label] (t Label)` as the pre-result. That would mean, we use the instantiation

```
    traverse :: Traversable t
      => (Label -> Either [Label] Label) -> t Label -> Either [Label] (t Label)
```

So what can we pass as the argument function?

```
travPt0 :: [Label] -> Label -> Either [Label] Label
travPt0 ls@(l0 : _) label
   | l0 /= label   = Left ls
   | otherwise     = Right label     ?
```

The problem is, `traverse` will then fail immediately and completely if *any* node has a non-matching label. `Traversable` doesn't actually have a notion of "selectively" diving down into a data structure, it just passes through everything, always. Actually, we only want to match on the topmost node at first, only that one is mandatory to match at first.

One way to circumvent immediate deep-traversal is to first split up the tree into a tree of sub-trees. Ok, so... we need to extract the topmost label. We need to split the tree in subtrees. [Reminds you of anything](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2/docs/Control-Comonad.html)?

```
trav' :: (Traversable t, Comonad t) => [Label] -> t Label -> [Label]
trav' (l0 : ls) tree
  | top <- extract tree
             = if top /= l0 then l0 : ls
               else let subtrees = duplicate tree
                    in  ... ?
```

Now amongst those subtrees, we're basically interested only in the one that matches. This can be determined from the result of `trav'`: if the second element is passed right back again, we have a failure. Unlike normal nomenclature with `Either`, this means *we wish to go on*, but not use that branch! So we need to return `Either [Label] ()`.

```
               else case ls of
                     []     -> [l0]
                     l1:ls' -> let subtrees = duplicate tree
                               in  case traverse (trav' ls >>> \case
                                                     (l1':_)
                                                       | l1'==l1 -> Right ()
                                                     ls''        -> Left ls''
                                                 ) subtrees of
                                      Left ls'' -> ls''
                                      Right _   -> l0 : ls   -- no matches further down.
```

***I have not tested this code***!

Comment: Nice! I actually toyed around with the `comonad` instance of `Tree` but couldn't come with a solution because I failed to understand what `duplicate` does.

Comment: Note that actually it does not do exactly what you'd like (encapsulate only the top-level in another tree wrapper), but transforms _every_ node into the respective subtree. That makes my solution quite horribly inefficient, _O_ (_n_ ² ⋅ log( _n_ )) it is I believe.

Comment: There is a small typo in your code: the `ls` in `case traverse ls >>> ...` should be `ls'` (SO didn't let me edit it). Otherwise it works as expected with other instances of `Comonad` and `Traversable` (I've tried `NonEmpty` and other custom tree variants). I'm now trying to come up with a more efficient way to make it work.

Comment: BTW, I could simplify the code a bit making `paths` `NonEmtpy` instead `[]`. In real life there'll always be a root label.

Comment: Cleaned up version of the code: https://gist.github.com/jdnavarro/d8882282405e4e20a025

Answer (score 2):

We'll take as reference the following recursive model

```
import           Data.List   (minimumBy)
import           Data.Ord    (comparing)
import           Data.Tree

-- | Follows a path into a 'Tree' returning steps in the path which
-- are not contained in the 'Tree'
treeTail :: Eq a => [a] -> Tree a -> [a]
treeTail [] _ = []
treeTail (a:as) (Node a' trees)
  | a == a'   = minimumBy (comparing length) 
              $ (a:as) : map (treeTail as) trees
  | otherwise = as
```

which suggests that the mechanism here is less that we're traversing through the tree accumulating (which is what a `Traversable` instance might do) but more that we're stepping through the tree according to some state and searching for the deepest path.

We can characterize this "step" by a `Prism` if we like.

```
import Control.Lens

step :: Eq a => a -> Prism' (Tree a) (Forest a)
step a = 
  prism' (Node a)
         (\n -> if rootLabel n == a 
                  then Just (subForest n)
                  else Nothing)
```

This would allow us to write the algorithm as

```
treeTail :: Eq a => [a] -> Tree a -> [a]
treeTail [] _ = []
treeTail pth@(a:as) t =
  maybe (a:as)
        (minimumBy (comparing length) . (pth:) . map (treeTail as))
        (t ^? step a)
```

but I'm not sure that's significantly more clear.

Comment: So I'd need to create a different `Prism` whenever I change the `Traversable` structure, right?

Comment: This is probably way more efficient than my comonad proposal. (What exactly does it generalise, though?)

Comment: @leftaroundabout The best I was aiming to do was talk about the relation to Traversable and lens.